# Facing connection error signalr in objective-c

Tags: ios, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

i am getting the following error while i am reciving the response of the connection

```
Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 400" UserInfo=0x7f9bb8492a80 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The ConnectionId is in the incorrect format., NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://63.134.216.208:8050/signalr/signalr/send?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=EUbfqwHFksD0ygZmJR6Mgjd/RD39nkuXol/o7XoC+yxiqoZN8Ge197elXcig1/2zrurVr32Iir3w6M6J0TX9HrTib+tvHvGFoEyvxHyRFrv4S4LaDXe2rV4nAV8Kmjgq, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7f9bb8422810> { URL: http://63.134.216.208:8050/signalr/signalr/send?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=EUbfqwHFksD0ygZmJR6Mgjd/RD39nkuXol/o7XoC+yxiqoZN8Ge197elXcig1/2zrurVr32Iir3w6M6J0TX9HrTib+tvHvGFoEyvxHyRFrv4S4LaDXe2rV4nAV8Kmjgq }, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f9bb8622200> { URL: http://63.134.216.208:8050/signalr/signalr/send?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=EUbfqwHFksD0ygZmJR6Mgjd/RD39nkuXol/o7XoC+yxiqoZN8Ge197elXcig1/2zrurVr32Iir3w6M6J0TX9HrTib+tvHvGFoEyvxHyRFrv4S4LaDXe2rV4nAV8Kmjgq } { status code: 400, headers {
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
"Content-Type" = "text/html";
Date = "Tue, 01 Sep 2015 09:54:36 GMT";
Expires = "-1";
Pragma = "no-cache";
Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.5";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
"X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
"X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
"X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 400}
```

**my code is as follows** 
here i am setting the proxy and url but still

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
SRHubProxy *chat ;
SRHubConnection *hubConnection;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

// Connect to the service
hubConnection = [SRHubConnection connectionWithURL:@"http://63.134.216.208:8050/"];
// Create a proxy to the chat service
hubConnection.delegate=self;
chat = [hubConnection createHubProxy:@"chatHub"];
[chat on:@"addMessage" perform:self selector:@selector(addMessage:)];
// Start the connection
[hubConnection start];
hubConnection.started = ^{
    NSLog(@"started");
};
hubConnection.received = ^(NSString * data) {
    NSLog(@"%@",data);
    NSError *jsonError;
    self.txtView.text=data;
    NSData *objectData = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                         options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                           error:&jsonError];
};



// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (void)addMessage:(NSString *)message {
// Print the message when it comes in
   // NSLog(message);
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)Connect:(id)sender {
  //   [hubConnection start];
[chat invoke:@"Connect" withArgs:@[@"08434ede-005e-4c05-b78f-4a703086660c",@"Dest",@"Are you there"] completionHandler:^(id response) {
    //
}];
}
#pragma mark- delgeates
- (void)SRConnectionDidOpen:(SRConnection *)connection
{
    //AQSK
NSLog(@"get connected using HubConnection");
self.txtView.text=@"get connected using HubConnection";
[chat invoke:@"Connect" withArgs:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Connect", nil]];

}

- (void)SRConnection:(SRConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSString *)data
{
//AQSK
self.txtView.text=@"data recieved";
self.txtView.text=data;
NSLog(@"data recieved %@",data);

}

- (void)SRConnectionDidClose:(SRConnection *)connection
{
self.txtView.text=@"close";
NSLog(@"close");
}

- (void)SRConnection:(SRConnection *)connection didReceiveError:(NSError *)error
 {
 self.txtView.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error.description];
NSLog(@"error%@",error.description);
}


- (IBAction)quit:(id)sender {
exit(0);
}
```

Please help if you are really know what is wrong happing here.

Comment: It would help if you provided the server and the client code.

Comment: my signalr working randomly sometimes it get connection and sometimes not able to fetch the data.

Comment: Still, you haven't provided any code

Comment: Your server is claiming you made a bad request. Are you able to get it to tell you what it thinks was wrong? Also try running via a proxy; if you can't see any difference between successful and failing requests then it's probably a server issue. If you can then whatever the difference is should help you to identify the client error.

Comment: The server is working fine with android device. Now my device is randomly connected to the server. But the issue is that its not always connected to the server. i don't know what i am doing wrong